# How to configure epstopdf for the Sphinx plantuml extension?

Tags: windows, python-sphinx, plantuml, rst2pdf

I'm trying to get Sphinx on Windows to generate a PDF with the rst2pdf plugin. My reStructuredText files make use of the PlantUML Sphinx extension.

When generating a PDF, I get the message

```
SphinxWarning: WARNING: epstopdf command 'epstopdf' cannot be run
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`epstopdf` is a Perl application, which can be [downloaded from CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf). Install [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/), and execute `epstopdf.pl` to test it:

```
D:\epstopdf>perl epstopdf.pl
Error: Input filename missing (try --help for more information)
```

Add the following to `conf.py`:

```
plantuml_epstopdf = 'perl "D:\epstopdf\epstopdf.pl"'
```

Install [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/), and add it to the path:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.20\bin"
```

Now you should be able to generate PDF's.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for Ubuntu by installing `texlive-font-utils`:

```
sudo apt install texlive-font-utils
```

This will make the `epstopdf` command available and fixed my Sphinx build with PlantUML.